# Netsuite Inventory Item Custom Forms keep changing

Tags: netsuite, inventory

We have created a custom form for certain inventory items in Netsuite. When we want to go back and edit that inventory item, it automatically goes back to our default custom form. We manually have to change the form back to what we want to use each time we edit these types of items.

Is there a way to have it so when these specific items are opened to edit that it will always go to the custom form that we originally created it on?

Answer (score 2):

No need to create a workflow/script. You just need to set the custom form to "Store Form with Record".

Customize the form and checked the option that says "Store Form with Record".

Every time you create an Item Record select the form and fill in the necessary information and save it. After saving it the form will be automatically saved with the record and it will be used every time you edit and view the record.

Definition of "Store Form with Record"
*Check this box to store this custom form with each record entered with this form.
This ensures that your records are viewed and edited with this form regardless of who is viewing or editing the record.*

Answer (score -1):

Options:
1. Add the custom form to the menu and choose that menu item when editing those types of inventory items.

2. Write a workflow (SuiteFlow) that opens the correct form based on the inventory item type.
3. Write SuiteScript that will open the correct form based on the inventory item type.

Comment: It appears that you're fine selecting the form and setting the checkbox when creating the item, but you don't want to select the form during edit?